# Multidomain store checkout redirected to default url

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, multistore, multidomain

I have a multi site store set up as follows:

Website1 (base) - Store1 - View1 (default)

Website2 - Store2 - View2

Each website has it's own domain (ie store.co.uk for Website1 and store.com for Website2).  My problem is that that checking out on Website2 redirects to the url for Website1 (store.co.uk/checkout/onepage/) which is not what I expected - we want the domain to remain store.com.

I'm not aware of any redirect rules in .htaccess that would cause this. Are there any admin settings that govern which checkout is to be used?

As this is the first multidomain store I've configured any advice given would be gratefully received.

Magento CE 1.9.2.4

*It's worth pointing out that the contacts page for both stores has a secure url too and isn't redirected like checkout.*

Comment: Other pages are working fine right??

Comment: Yes Asish, everything is working as expected until I hit checkout

Comment: are you using any other checkout???

Comment: We're using the standard CE One Step Checkout.  As it happens having completely cleared all caches again, including, this time, 'Cache Storage', and restarted apache the problem appears to have changed subtly.  Now when clicking 'checkout' I am being taken to the shopping cart page rather than the checkout, but still on Website1's 'default' domain rather than the Website2 domain as expected.

Comment: cookie problem. Please add right info on admin panel cookie management section

Comment: Unfortunately the 'cookie domain', under 'Session Cookie Management', is correctly set for both stores

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end this turned out to be an issue with configuration of the full page caching plugin I was using - [Lesti FPC](https://github.com/GordonLesti/Lesti_Fpc.'Lesti%20FPC'). Once the plugin was correctly configured the issue disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Check your secure URL is correct for the faulty store/website. Checkout will often switch to SSL so looks up a different base URL to the unsecure  site.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Robbie but both base and secure urls are correct for both stores.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the contacts page for both stores is a secure url too and isn't redirected like checkout.